# Make two divs, one below the other in a single column, have the height of the highest without JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to have two `div`s in a single column, where one is on top of the other, so that both have the height of the "tallest" div without using Javascript?

Here is some example code:

```
<div class="col col-6-lg">
  <div id="inner1"></div>
  <div id="inner2"></div>
</div>
```

I have used Javascript successfully and I have tried using flex with a good article here: http://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/gpard but it did not work as I had hoped. All divs in a single "row" are adjusted to the highest div but it does not carry down through multiple "rows".

I am wondering is there another non JS solution?

I was/am wary about tagging Javascript and jQuery but I felt it was appropriate.

Comment: Not that I know about...

Comment: "it did not work" is not very helpful in solving your problem.  How exactly did it not work?  What went wrong?  What's the desired result? Can you create a minimal example of the problem?

Comment: Essentially...no. Not even with flexbox.

Comment: @JosephMarikle, I have updated my answer but will not be providing an example. When you read the article you will also see this in action, thanks.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, because is not going to work. `vh` refers to the viewport size, not the current element size.

Comment: Height  of child divs is based on the parent height...if that isn't known how can the child height be 50% of it. ?

Comment: Figured I'd chime in and echo what everyone else has already said - no, there is no way to do this with just CSS. Flexbox can only maintain the same height of sibling divs if they are on the same row (next to each other). It cannot maintain the same height of sibling divs once they have been collapsed (are on top of each other).

Comment: Ok @Adam, there doesn't seem to be any alternatives to flexbox either.